# Twilio-Ruby 407 Authentication Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, twilio

I'm working on a Rails app.  It uses Twilio-Ruby to send some phone number validation requests.

In the console I do:

```
 @client ||= Twilio::REST::LookupsClient.new 
        "AC1230503237c2647f7f9d5821c6f39e64", 
        "f8829cefe14193cf35d5ec443f5f3e87"

        response = @client.phone_numbers.get("1235585781")
        response.phone_number
```

and it gives me the following error:

```
Net::HTTPServerException: 407 "Proxy Authentication Required"
        from ~/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/net/http/response.rb:119:in `error!'
```

Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Twilio does this as a quite clever hack to encrypt the password.

See here https://andrewjprokop.wordpress.com/2015/01/27/understanding-sip-authentication/.

Twilio-Ruby would need to implement support for this.

Answer (score -1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Looks like you're behind a proxy and need to give the [Twilio Lookups Client](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/lookups) the details. You can pass these in when you initialize the client. Like this:

```
@client ||= Twilio::REST::LookupsClient.new(
  account_sid, 
  auth_token,
  proxy_addr: proxy_addr # The domain of a proxy through which you'd like the client to make HTTP requests.
  proxy_port: proxy_port # The port on which to connect to the above proxy.
  proxy_user: proxy_user # The user name to use for authentication with the proxy.
  proxy_pass: proxy_pass # The password to use for authentication with the proxy.
)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I don't think I'm behind a proxy.  I have no idea what these credentials would be :/

Comment: Ok, but you can see in the original error that you are getting a proxy authentication issue. Is this your own network, or can you ask someone about the proxy settings?

Comment: It's on my home network.  My computer hardwired to a router and that's all.  Is there a config setting in the gem that might be the problem?

Comment: Are you able to make http requests to other URLs?

Comment: Yeah, everything else works.  Other APIs, browser requests, etc.

Comment: having the same issue. For some reason Twilio wants Proxy Authentication for SIP even though I am not behind any proxy.  It seems Twilio does this as a (quite clever) hack to encrypt the password for SIP, but I still get a 403 error after.

Comment: The Lookups API is an HTTP API so this wouldn't have anything to do with SIP. The original question was about a 407 error too. What is the code you are using that is causing you to get a 403?